# No display on resume from suspend

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, suspend

My netbook display stays black after resume from suspend about 70% of the time. The only remedy is to either close the lid and open again (to sleep the system) and see if that brought the display back, or kill the system (yank the battery or hold the power switch) and reboot cold.

Acer AOD250 Intel 945GSE (GMA 950 graphics) chipset.
Xubuntu 12.10

I have seen questions like this asked again and again and never answered. For several years now. This is not a new bug, this is a very very very old bug that nobody seems to be interested in fixing. But guess what? Windows XP suspend works just fine.

Yes, I wiggle my finger on the touchpad. Yes I hit every single key on the keyboard. Yes, I tried Ctrl-Alt-F1. Yes, I even tried plugging in a USB mouse and wiggling it too.

There is no xconfig file in /etc/X11 to edit.

Does anybody anywhere in the Linux universe have an answer to this question, or does nobody on the planet use it on a laptop, and therefore couldn't care less if suspend works?

Hello?
Bueller?
Bueller?

Comment: I used to have a working suspend on a Dell xps 1330 with the same GMA 950 since ubuntu 7.04, however it was broken on several iterations (read: non-LTS-kernels) and I haven't tried since 12.04, where it worked. Who is Bueller anyway?

Comment: @aquaherd reference to "Ferris Bueller's Day Off" where the dumb teacher slowly realizes Bueller isn't there. It's a euphemism for "Is there anybody out there who could be bothered to answer the @$#@%#$ question already?"

Comment: @aquaherd Suspend has never worked reliably on this machine, on LTS11 or LTS12, or on the non-LTS releases in between.